# Rails belongs_to association is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Here is my Course model

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :longdescription, :shortdescription, :title, :published_at
  has_many :lessons,  :foreign_key => 'course_id'
end
```

And Here is my Lesson model

```
class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course, :class_name => 'Course'
  attr_accessor :course_id
  attr_accessible :description, :title, :course_id
end
```

I creates a lesson that belongs to a course. lesson created successfully

```
 Lesson.create(:title => "testing", :description => "causing problems", :course_id => 1)
```

But when i fetch a record of lesson I got course_id=nil. Any Help???

```
<Lesson id: 8, title: "testing", description: "causing problems", course_id: nil, created_at: "2013-03-15 12:56:36", updated_at: "2013-03-15 12:56:36">
```

Comment: Are you passing `course_id` while creating `lesson`? Post the code of creating `lesson`.

Comment: yes courses are being displayed in selection dropdown I select a course to attach with lesson but at lesson show page Course field is nil

Comment: Because `course_id` is not saved. Put `validates :course_id, :presence => true` line in your `Lesson` model. It will not let any `lesson` created with `nil course_id`

Comment: After putting that constraint it is being saved as like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to remove the `attr_accessor :course_id` line in your model.  If you have this line, it creates the following methods in your model which conflicts with what is defined by default

```
def course_id
  @course_id
end

def course_id=(cid)
  @course_id = cid
end
```

Comment: If I remove that line I got this error "ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: courses_id"

Comment: you're passing in `courses_id` not `course_id`. check your code.

Comment: I correct that error courses by mistaken but the orignal issue is there as it was

Comment: can you add your entire lesson model in a gist?

Comment: hmm so that's your entire lesson model. not really sure what's wrong here. are you sure you've removed that attr_accessor line? also try `course.lessons.create`.

Comment: Thank you Sir I removed that line and it is working fine I forgot to remove that one earlier

Answer (score 2):

Remove `attr_accessor :course_id` in your `Lesson` model. This will override the default behavior of the activerecord.

Comment: If I remove that line I got this error "ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: courses_id"